# MC40 Application UI changing when Scanner Enabled (Android OS)

Tags: rhomobile, rhodes

I am developing RhoMobile Application for Motorola MC40 device. When I include app_type: "rhoelements" in build.yml for enabling the scanner, the UI getting shrink but scanner is working perfectly. If I am not including the app_type, UI is perfect but scanner is not working. Anybody can help me to solve this issue?

Thanks,

Augustine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're getting the Motorola Webkit Browser rendering engine instead of the native Android browser.

Be sure to use the latest version of the RhoMobile Suite v2.2SP1 or v4.0beta59, available on [Launchpad](http://developer.motorolasolutions.com).

To be sure to get the native browser rendering engine you can add the **native_browser** capability to the build.yml configuration file in your project and be sure that the **non_motorola_device** cabability is not listed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I just used RhoMobile Suite v4.0 and the problem get over.